# Migrating complete HTML and Javascript application into vaadin UI components

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Many thanks for your help and support. I am just a beginner in Vaadin 7 and I am badly need of help.

Let me explain,

We have a third party application developed in HTML and JavaScripts. On my PC, if i open the html page with the browser it works fine. Please find the application in the attachment.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mdxFaMJmUb2pSTdh87MC8oSaaDMGx19d/view?usp=sharing

Now the challenge is, I need to in-corporate that application (HTML + Javascript) into Vaadin 7 as follows,

1. In-corporate the Javascripts into Vaadin using AbstractJavaScriptComponent (This has been done somehow understanding the examples)

Now comes the challenge,

If you open the HTML in the textpad/notepad, you could notice lot of div tags from the " < body > " tag. The requirement is, each div tag is a html component and this should be converted into vaadin component with css styling and need to be displayed in the UI, so that based on the customer requirements, we can change the style css. I tried with custom layout but this is not way to be implemented as well, this does not require a widget and server side component to be implemented. Is there any other way to implemented ? I spending lot of time but all my efforts are in-vain.  I just need the way forward to give me a right direction if you have any idea.

Comment: Having whole application as s single component sounds really monolithic approach. What would be the logical public API for that component be in this case? CSS should not be the problem here, and maybe CustomLayout could also work for layouting. With AbstractJavaScriptComponent you use the JS library and introduce a API connector. Like here: https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/client/js/MyComponent.java

Comment: I would strongly suggest to migrate to vaadin 10 or higher, since vaadin 7 will be out of support next month. (February 2019) https://vaadin.com/roadmap

Comment: I wouldn't hurry on migration. Especially 7 to 10 is a huge step, almost like different products, even though some core things are the same. There are still a lot of features and plugins missing from Vaadin 10+. Vaadin 7 apps will continue to work after the "official support" is over just fine and there are ways to continue the support even further. https://vaadin.com/blog/ways-to-extend-vaadin-7-app-support

Upgrade to Vaadin 8 is much easier, especially if you use compatibility packages, and then you'll get years of new "free support".